# jQuery $.each for specific keys within an array of objects

Tags: jquery, object, each

I have this array of objects below and i want to iterate with `$.each` and get the *type* and *description*

```
Object[
 Object { 
   advert_id=7,
   type="entipo",
   description="magazine"
 }, 
 Object { 
   advert_id=8,
   type="tv",
   description="commercials"
 }
]
```

Comment: Looks like an array of objects to me...

Comment: Yes you are right, i'm fixing it right now.

Comment: Then where are you stuck, the DOC regarding $.each as some examples in it. BTW, what do you want to do with result?

Comment: I'm new to jQuery and i do not know hot to achieve that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume it was assigned to variable `MyObject`. This should do it:

```
$.each(MyObject, function(index){
   console.log(MyObject[index].type);
   console.log(MyObject[index].description);
});
```

The above is rather tedious. Another way you could do it would be as follows:

```
$.each(MyObject, function(index, obj){
   console.log(obj.type);
   console.log(MyObject[index].description);
});
```

And finally, as follows:

```
$.each(MyObject, function(){
   console.log(this.type);
   console.log(this.description);
});
```

Of course you would replace `console.log()` with whatever it is you want to do with the values.

You may be wondering why you don't JUST use `this`? You may of course just use the approach that implements `this`, but the benefit of using one that has the index and the object in, is that you may need to programmatically do something with the index position of the object, in which case you have it easily accessible to you. That's not to say you could not easily get it when using only the `this` approach, but it makes life that much easier.

Comment: `function(obj)` obj is the index

Comment: Correct, I simply used obj as each index contains an object, which just makes more sense to me ;) Just a personal thing :p

Comment: As far if i `console.log(obj)` i can view in the console the index. But i cannot view the object's key `console.log(obj.type)`, returns "undefined".

Comment: use `this` instead of `obj`

Comment: Ok, it worked by using `this`. Please can you suggest an article to read about this? I want to understand `function(_, obj)` and how `this` works.

Comment: I updated my answer using the index of the MyObject, but you can just as well use `this`, it's really up to you.

Comment: @Makis - `this` simply references the current object in the loop as it iterates over all the objects. It's like looking through a stack of books and saying "I like THIS one, let me see how many pages THIS one has"

Comment: @Makis - I added 3 methods that you could use. You will see that in one I used `index` and `obj` as this follows the `key => value` notion, which is generally what arrays and objects consists of in the simplest form. Note, and array IS an object, I just decouple them as people often don't see them as being the same sort of thing. Each entry in the object has a key (or index) and the value in your case will be an object at each key. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much @SimonDowdles I wish i could vote you one more time! Very nice approach and a nice explanation!

Comment: Always a pleasure @Makis

Comment: Beware, an object has not any index unlike an array. I say that because reading your comment could be misleading. In your case, you would have better to rename your variable as `myArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$(yourArray).each(function(){
   console.log(this.type);
   console.log(this.description);
);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `$.fn.each` on none jq array like object

Comment: That's why i first convert the Array to a jQuery object: `$(yourArray)`. Its same as this `$.each(yourArray,function(){})`. Same thing, different syntax.

Comment: I missed that sorry but then it is quite useless anyway